# python config ini file - automatically identify data types?

Tags: python, types, config, ini

I want to parse a config.ini file into a dictionary a la [Automatically read configuration values in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309914/automatically-read-configuration-values-in-python]), but automatically identifying the data **types** - as much as possible - in some clever fashion. Is there a way to do this, or must it be coded by hand, and if so what is a good way to go? Thanks!

Here's an example:

```
[multinest]
n_live_points       = 500 ; or 1000
multimodal          = False ; Posterior unlikely to be multimodal
max_modes           = 1
seed                = 1234  ; [-1 for clock]
do_ins              = False
max_iter            = 0
evidence_tolerance  = 0.5
mode_tolerance      = -1e90
outstem             = 1-
```

I would like a loader that can differentiate the main standard python types: strings, floats, integers, booleans, lists, dictionaries, plus numpy arrays.

These are also helpful (but old?):

[Automatically Type Cast Parameters In Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019283/automatically-type-cast-parameters-in-python)

[automatic detection/conversion of data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020081/automatic-detection-conversion-of-data-types)

Comment: What does your config.ini look like? Could you post an excerpt?

Comment: Hm, ini files are all about easy editable and parseable key value storage for strings. Without further details on your application's world view (data / domain model) I do not see a general  solution. If you add some constraining details to the question, there might be someone willing to explain a clever idea ;-) Sample: Fixed, finite set of allowed names, use the "matching" type conversion functors stored in a map.

Comment: PyYAML will infer all of those types except numpy arrays.  You can also explicitly define your schema with a validator such as cerberus and pass your ini-derived dict through.  http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/usage.html